# How to split the given 'key-value' list into two lists separated as 'keys' and 'values' with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, pycharm, key-value

This is my List

```
List = ['function = function1', 'string = string1', 'hello = hello1', 'new = new1', 'test = test1']
```

I need to separate the List into two differnt List's sepearted as 'keys' and 'values'

```
List = ['function = function1', 'string = string1', 'hello = hello1', 'new = new1', 'test = test1']
```

KeyList

```
KeyList = ['function', 'string', 'hello', 'new', 'test']
```

ValueList

```
ValueList = ['function1', 'string1', 'hello1', 'new1', 'test1']
```

Comment: Iterate through the list, split each item at the '"' sign, append to list. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

There are different possible approach. One is the method proposed by Tim, but if you are not familiar with re you could also do:

```
List = ['function = function1', 'string = string1', 'hello = hello1', 'new = new1', 'test = test1']

KeyList = []
ValueList = []
for item in List:
    val = item.split(' = ')
    KeyList.append(val[0])
    ValueList.append(val[1])
    
print(KeyList)
print(ValueList)
```

and the output is:

```
['function', 'string', 'hello', 'new', 'test']
['function1', 'string1', 'hello1', 'new1', 'test1']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `split(" = ")` and unzip the list of key-value pairs to two tuples:

```
keys, values = zip(*map(lambda s: s.split(" = "), List))

# keys
# >>> ('function', 'string', 'hello', 'new', 'test')
# values
# >>>('function1', 'string1', 'hello1', 'new1', 'test1')
```

This is based on the fact that `zip(*a_zipped_iterable)` works as an unzipping function.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `re.findall` here:

```py
inp = ['function = function1', 'string = string1', 'hello = hello1', 'new = new1', 'test = test1']
keys = [re.findall(r'(\w+) =', x)[0] for x in inp]
vals = [re.findall(r'\w+ = (\w+)', x)[0] for x in inp]
```

Comment: your code is not working sir :)

Answer (score 0):

```py
keys = [pair[0] for pair in pairs]
values = [pair[1] for pair in pairs]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).